# Show that the following language is undecidable

Tags: formal-languages, undecidability, halting-problem, oracle-machines

$\{ M \mid M
\text{ is a machine that runs in }100n^3 + 300\text{ time }\}$

I am currently stuck with this one. I thought of reducing *HALT* to *M* as the reduction seems legitimate to me: if the first is undecidable then building an instance of the first problem starting from the second, ie asking if a machine M that executes an input n stops after a time $f$$(n)$ is like asking if it stops at all and then **M ⊆ HALT**. However there is something that does not convince me in this demonstration because it seems quite naive and I don't think that this is enough to prove that this language is undecidable. In addition the exercise it is taken from a chapter of a text in which the oracles are introduced, is it possible to prove this language undecidable by means of oracles? I would appreciate your help, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't defined HALT, so let me assume that it consists of all Turing machines that halt on the empty input. If $M$ halts in time $f(n)$, then in particular it halts on the empty input, and so if $M$ belongs to your language then it also belongs to halt. But the converse doesn't hold, and $L \subseteq HALT$ doesn't imply anything about $L$ (for example, $\emptyset \subseteq HALT$, yet $\emptyset$ is decidable).

In other words, your proof doesn't work. It doesn't prove anything.

Your goal is to show that using an oracle to $L$ (your language), you can decide the halting problem; hence if $L$ were decidable, then so would HALT be, contrary to the known fact that HALT isn't decidable.

In fact, we can show that $L$ is coRE-hard. This means that there is a computable reduction that takes a description of a Turing machine $M$ and outputs a description of another Turing machine $M'$ such that:

1. If $M$ halts on the empty input then $M'$ *doesn't* run in time $f(n) := 100n^3 + 300$.
2. If $M$ doesn't halt on the empty input then $M'$ *does* run in time $f(n)$.

The construction goes as follows. On input of length $n$, $M'$ simulates $M$ on the empty input for $g(n)$ steps, where $g(n)$ is a function to be determined, which tends to infinity. If $M$ halts within $g(n)$ steps, $M'$ goes into an infinite loop, and otherwise $M'$ halts. We choose $g(n)$ so that the simulation runs in time $f(n)$. (Depending on the exact Turing machine model, we might be able to take $g(n) = n$ or so.)

If $M$ doesn't halt then, by construction, $M'$ also halts within $f(n)$ steps. If $M$ does halt, then for large enough $n$, $M'$ will never halt, and in particular won't halt within $f(n)$ steps.

The language $L$ is also coRE: we can enumerate machines not in $L$ by running all machines on all inputs, and outputting the description of a machine once it doesn't stop within $f(n)$ steps on some input of length $n$. This shows that $L$ is coRE-complete.

Comment: thank you for your exhaustive answer. I easily understood the demonstration of the belonging of the language to  coRE  but i miss the exact point in which the undecidability of L is proved and in particular the way in which this is established through oracles ...

Comment: It’s not established through oracles. It’s established through a many-one reduction, which is a much weaker notion.